# Skip entering new date in windows 98 batch file

Tags: date, batch-file, dos, windows-98

I create a test.bat file , edit , write DATE and save it.

when i run the bat it show current date then ask for new date , to skip this step i should press enter .

I want to skip entering new date or make it auto press enter .

Comment: Oh wow, this is one of those increasingly rare circumstances where you can _actually_ use the [dos] tag.

Comment: WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 98, really?!

You can do it like this:

```
echo 2019-01-02|date
```

The `2019-01-02` part should be the same when you manually input the date.
So if the prompt let's you input `mm-dd-yy`, you should change that to `01-02-19` like date.

For automatically `Enter` to date, do this:

```
echo.|date
```

If you are not setting a new date, but just output the current date,
then(not work in Win98):

```
date /T
```

Comment: `date /T` is almost certainly what they're looking for

Comment: quite sure, `date` *hasn't*  the `/t` switch in DOS (Win98).  I think, there isn't even the `%date%` or `%time%`variables.

Comment: when i use date /t , i receive invalid date enter new date (MM-DD-YY) so idk if it's working or not , using %date% i receive nothing

Comment: can i compare the date ? @AdamSmith

Comment: Comparing? In DOS? I guess it's nearly impossible (or *maybe* with a *lot* of ugly code). Whatever you want to do, you really should use a programming language (Isn't there QBASIC with Win98?)

Comment: Yes it's possible after search i could do it but without space or current date
Code 
SET DATE1="Wed 01-02-2019"
ECHO. %DATE1%
SET DATE2="Wed 01-02-2019"
ECHO. %DATE2%
IF %DATE1%==%DATE2% ECHO DATE OKEY
IF NOT %DATE1%==%DATE2% ECHO DATE NOT OEKY
@Stephan

Comment: ah - check, if they are the same. Yes, of course. Sorry, most people that ask "compare dates" actually want the difference between two dates.

Comment: i just want to check if they are the same but i could not do it 
If statement in windows 98 uses string ( i can not use space ) only and i can not use DATE ( current date ) after == 
should i go for QBASIC ?
@Stephan

Comment: The "days of DOS" are long ago for me, so I might be wrong, but `if "a b"=="a  b" ...`might work